# How do you insert a new user every minute using a mySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

I am wondering if there is a way to add a new user automatically in a mysql  table every minute or so ?

I have a USER table and a USER ACTIVE table, when ever a user is active the details goes under the USER ACTIVE table. I would like to automatically be able to add and delete x number of users from the USER ACTIVE table every minute.

How do I achieve this? I am also a beginner with PHP (which is what I am using) MySQL.

Comment: not very clear, but cron comes to mind

Comment: Insert 1/60th of a user every second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do what you want in pure PHP. PHP is designed to render a page on request and then finish, it won't keep running with a timer. You can either set up a cron job as Dagon suggests, or look at adding some java or similar that keeps running a timer once the page is loaded - which I don't think you want, because that would still require the page to be open somewhere.

I have something similar set up using only PHP, the cron job simply launches the PHP interpreter to run the page every so often: "php /home/user/timer.php". Exactly how you set this up is going to depend on what level of access you have to the system and what commands are available, but most web hosts will allow the setup of a basic cron job.